# activity doesn't start while OnclikcListener is i=used

Tags: android, google-pay

helleo. here's my issue: i created a payment function ,but it just doesn't start the activity i want it to start due to a function being deprecated. so basically, it does nothing (hopefully it doesn't crash), but i can't show it to my tutor. here's the code:

```
mBoutonPaye.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener( ) {
      

  @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                    .scheme("upi")
                    .appendQueryParameter("pa", "test@creditmutuel")
                    .appendQueryParameter("pn", "TacosKing")
                    .appendQueryParameter("mc", "1234")
                    .appendQueryParameter("tr", "123456789")
                    .appendQueryParameter("tn", "test")
                    .appendQueryParameter("am","10.01")
                    .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
                    .appendQueryParameter("url", "https://tes.merchant.website")
                    .build();
            Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
            intent.setData(uri);
            intent.setPackage(GOOGLE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GOOGLE);

        }
    });

    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_GOOGLE)
        Log.d("result" , data.getStringExtra("Status"));
```

does anyone have a simple alternative to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void nextPayMethod(Uri uri) {
        Intent upiPayIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        upiPayIntent.setData(uri);

        // will always show a dialog to user to choose an app
        Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with");

        // check if intent resolves
        if(null != chooser.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())) {
            startActivityForResult(chooser, UPI_PAYMENT);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(Sub2.this,"No UPI app found, please install one to continue",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

I have managed like this

Comment: so basically, i have to replace everything after my intent.ACTION_VIEW by that code?

Comment: Just pass that Uri to this method

Comment: does it work on Google Pay?

Comment: Every UPI payment App will Work